# How do I print a list of numbers on each line in clojure?

Tags: loops, printing, clojure, println

how can I print a list of n, say 10, numbers on 10 lines? I just learned about loop and recur, but cannot seem to combine a side-effect `(println i)` with `(recur (+ i 1))` in a loop form.
Just to be very clear: I'd like output like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

when n is 10.

Answer (score 16):

You can use doseq for this, which is meant to be used when iteration involves side effects,

```
(doseq [i (range 10)]
   (println i))
```

You could use map as pointed but that will produce a sequence full of nils which is both not idiomatic and wastes resources also doseq is not lazy so no need to force it with doall.

Comment: This prints number 0 to 9; using (inc i) in the println, as shown in the other answers below, gives 1 to 10.

Comment: instead of inc just do (range 1 11)

Answer (score 11):

I suggest *dotimes* for this kind of simple loop:

```
(dotimes [i 10]
  (println (inc i)))
```

Note that *dotimes* is non-lazy, so it is good for things like println that cause side effects.

Answer (score 3):

With loop/recur:

```
(loop [i 1]
  (when (<= i 10)
    (println i)
    (recur (inc i))))
```

However, it's more idiomatic (read: more "Clojuristic") to [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) the function println over the numbers in 1..10. But because map returns a lazy sequence, you must [force its evaluation with doall](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall):

```
(doall (map println (range 1 (inc 10))))
```

Comment: In fact it is more idiomatic to use `doseq` (or `dotimes`) in this case, because it is all about side-effects. `map` should only be used if you are interested in the return value. Otherwise you get easily caught by laziness.

Comment: So that would be
    (dotimes [i 10] (println i))
Thanks! Will remember that when I get to chapter 14 in 'Practical Clojure' (now finishing up chapter 3) :-)

Answer (score 0):

And just to be comprehensive you can do it with map also:

```
(doseq (map #(println %) (range 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print the output on the screen, you might also simply put a `(println i)` before entering your conditional:

```
(loop [i 0]
  (println i)
  (if (< i 10)
    (recur (inc i))
    (println "done!")))
```

And the output will be one number per line.